"Binary" Collation in SQL Server
I am working with a legacy database that uses wonky string values as primary keys.
For example, I might find the following primary keys in the same table:
aa
aA
Aa
AA
aa{Space}
AA{Space}
A{Space}A

What collation in SQL Server will best enable me to have primary keys that are case-sensitive and whitespace-sensitive?
I'm currently using Latin_General_100_BIN2_UTF8 but that seems to be whitespace insensitive.

Trailing spaces in strings won't be treated as separate for this purpose in any collation.

If you want "Whitespace sensitive" then you want a varbinary value, not a varchar with a binary collation. 'abc   ' is equal to 'abc' in any collation, however, 0x616263202020 and 0x616263 are not equal with varbinary values.

Personally (and I know this likely isn't possible for you, but it's worth exploring), I'd look to add a surrogate key column.

@ThomA This depend of the language alphabet because of BIDI codes. In Hebrew or Arabic this is the reverse...

If you want case, accent, etc, and "white space" sensitive values, then a varchar is the wrong data type. Part of the SQL language (as a whole, I'm not specifically talking about the T-SQL dialect specifically), is that string values should be treated as equal when they have a differing number of trailing white space characters: 'space' = 'space ' = 'space   ' = 'space                  '. Within SQL Server this doesn't change if you're using a different collation; it applies to all collations.
As a result a varchar won't help you as a PRIMARY KEY would treat the values 'space' and 'space ' as equal and thus your constraint would generate an error.
What you can use instead is a (var)binary, which you may chose to be a computed column. Then you can create your PRIMARY KEY on that. I'm going to use a binary value here, which is fixed width as it feels more appropriate. This means that a value like 'abc' would be stored as something like 0x616263000000 while 'abc   ' would be stored as 0x616263202020.
So, your table definition might look something like this:
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (StringID varchar(25) NOT NULL,
                            BinaryID AS ISNULL(CONVERT(binary(25), StringID),0x), --If StringID is an nvarchar, don't forget to double the number. ISNULL to enforce NOT NULL
                            /* Some more columns here*/
                            CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (BinaryID), --You might want this clustered, but is this always ascending?
                            INDEX CI_YourTable CLUSTERED (StringID)); --I know this isn't ascending either, but giving an example

Then we can do some test inserts and even though the StringIDs will be seen as equal (see the results of the SELECT), the PRIMARY KEY won't be, so they succeed:
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (StringID)
VALUES('abc'),
      ('abc   '),
      ('abc '),
      ('Abc '),
      ('ABc '),
      ('apples'),
      ('Apples');
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable;
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE StringID = 'abc';
GO
--Clean up
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;

